# factorising polynomials related proofs

Tags: polynomials, proof-verification, cyclic-groups

$P(x)= a{x}^3+b{x}^2+c{x}+d$ where $a,d$ are not equal to zero. (All the coefficients are integer) 
Now $P(x)$ is divided by $x-r$.

Here why r needs to be an integer to be a factor of d(constant term)?

Comment: It's not clear what you mean.  By definition, a factor of an integer must be an integer.  Did you mean to ask why a root that is an integer must be a factor of $d$?

Comment: Actually here I was using the concept of factor theorem of polynomials and remainder theorem. From remainder theorem we get P(r)= ar^3+br^2+cr+d =0. Then -d= (ar^2+br+c)r. So why r should be integer?

Comment: It shouldn't.  For example, none of the roots of $2 x^3 + 1$ are integers.

Comment: Sorry sir I didn't get that. Pls clear me.

Comment: $P(x) = 2 x^3 + 1 = 2 x^3 + 0 x^2 + 0 x + 1$ is a polynomial of the given form.   Its roots are not integers.